# Compare blank rows in 2 worksheets,insert blank rows if found different In VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert blank rows into 2 worksheets after comparison between the 2 using `Col A` Or `Col B` as the guide. And I have more than 10 Columns and lots of rows. Maybe I try to explain with a simplified example below:

Sheet1

```
A    B    C               
1    2    3  
111  222  333  
1111 2222 3333
```

Sheet2

```
A    B    C               
1    2    3  
11   22   33  
1111 2222 3333
```

**After compare**

Sheet1

```
A    B    C               
1    2    3  
(insert a blank row)  
111  222  333  
1111 2222 3333
```

Sheet2

```
A    B    C               
1    2    3  
11   22   33  
(insert a blank row)  
1111 2222 3333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need more details on the example. The logic of the blank rows appears to be adding a blank row whenever there isn't a match in the opposite table. However, this is going to be very tricky to do unless they're always sorted on a specific column in the same direction. I'm not sure on the specific code, but I think the logic of it would be a nested loop that checked each row of sheet B against a row of sheet A. While it checks, it should also carry a variable with the closest match to the value that wasn't greater than the value. That way, if it doesn't find a match it can insert a blank row after the closest match without going over. You'd then run the same code to then check every value in B against all the rows in A.

Comment: this explanation is close. i cant explain well so i explain in a simplified example. My VBA is not good ..

Answer (score 0):

Play Around:

```
Sub InsertBlankIfNotMatched()

    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim lngDataCounter As Long
    Dim lngRowCount As Long
    Dim varData1 As Variant
    Dim varData2 As Variant

    Dim chk As Integer
    chk = 1
    Set rngA = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngB = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    lngRowCount = rngA.Rows.Count
    For lngDataCounter = 1 To lngRowCount
        varData1 = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rngA.Rows(lngDataCounter).Value))
        varData2 = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rngB.Rows(lngDataCounter).Value))

        If chk = 1 Then
            If Join(varData1, "") <> Join(varData2, "") Then
                rngA.Rows(lngDataCounter).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                lngRowCount = lngRowCount + 1
                chk = 2
            End If
        ElseIf chk = 2 Then
            If Join(varData1, "") <> Join(varData2, "") Then
                rngB.Rows(lngDataCounter).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                lngRowCount = lngRowCount + 1
                chk = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: " Application.transpose " using this is because you are sort like of adding up the whole column of "range A1" ?

" If Join(varData1, "") <> Join(varData2, "")  "  This line i don't 
understand, please someone explain to me, thank you

Arya : Thank you for providing such a nice coding sample. i played around with it i found what i need.THank you

Comment: 1. you need to compare 2 rows so have to be in a single stage so i used join it joins array with a delimiter like in first row its 1|2|3 i take it in an array and join with "" to the result would be 123.

Comment: 2. if you debug the code check only **rngA.Rows(lngDataCounter).Value** and check with **Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rngA.Rows(lngDataCounter).Value))**, this is just to clear unnecessary dimension for the **varData1 **

Comment: and at least you should upward my ans...